# "The name 'Page' is defined in the libraries 'package:burn_off/widgets/page.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I was trying to test this app in flutter, but I was unable to run the app because apper this error "The name 'Page' is defined in the libraries 'package:burn_off/widgets/page.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart'." I already tried to change the name of the class and variables and it didn't work. I need some help

Project: https://github.com/huextrat/BurnOff

Comment: **If you have conflict between two packages of same** ***method/widgets/class*** . Then , first import your package with a ***variable***  as follows:-

**`import 'package:QualityCheckApp/upgrade/screens/home/navigation_drawer.dart' as nav;`**

Then use your **method/class/widget** with this variable.

**`drawer: nav.NavigationDrawer(),`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 libraries referencing 'Page' as a widget: one is inside the widgets folder and the other one is from Flutter itself. So you need to use a prefix in your import; For example:

`import 'package:burn_off/widgets/page.dart' as mypage;`

and then you need to use your widget with that prefix, for example:

```
                mypage.Page(
                  title: "HOW TO BURN OFF",
                  background: aliment.background,
                  icon: aliment.bottomImage,
                  child: CardItem(
                    child: AlimentWidget(
                      aliment: aliment,
                      theme: aliment.background,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: In my case, I have my own Style class which is conflicting with one of libraries.
There are some static methods in my Style class which i am unable to access using this way. Please suggest a change.
(Note - I can not rename my class name)